# When a variable added into an ArrayList changes, does ArrayList update on its own?

Tags: arraylist

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);
    listlist.add(list);

    temp = list;
    temp.add(30);
    listlist.set(0,temp);

    System.out.println("size before temp is cleared: " + listlist.get(0).size());
    temp.clear();
    System.out.println("size after temp is cleared: " + listlist.get(0).size());
}

Output:
size before temp is cleared: 3
size after temp is cleared: 0
```

Here is a simplified portion of my code that is causing the problem. You can see how `temp` is being added to the `listlist`, and when `temp` is cleared after that action, the `listlist` seems to update itself and clear its contents in index 0 as well.

Is it true that the `ArrayList` updates itself whenever a variable used to insert a value is changed? Help needed.

Comment: Yes, the objects stored in a list can be modified. The list only stores references to objects. It doesn't matter if the properties of those references are modified.

Comment: My best friend is in the phonebook. I looked him up, called, and asked how old he is, and he said 25. Next year he'll be 26. Will the phonebook be automatically updated?

Comment: @jspcal I guess that's a thing... thanks!

Comment: This is the problem with using mutable objects. You need to be careful who you give references to, and how those references are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrayList will keep references to the things you give it. In your case, temp and list are both references to the same object (So there is no need to do the set in listlist). When you do temp.clear, the list object referenced by "temp" and "list" (Which is the same) gets cleared. Your list of lists keeps a reference to that same object. It's not "updating itself automatically". It doesnt need to, it never made a copy. Im attaching a diagram that might help you understand. The circles represent objects. the arrows mean that a reference exists to the object being pointed (Either contained in another obect or its yours and i wrote the name/identifier)

[image: diagram]

Comment: Awesome explanation. I get it now. Thanks for help.